# error: The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

I am doing this in another screen This is giving me this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3y7R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CCHx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Generate your Widget list in initState method.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    final List<Widget> card = your code here
    super.initState();
  }
```